# Run script at startup in /etc/init.d/

Tags: 12.04

Trying to make my script run at startup by placing it in `/etc/init.d/`. But this doesn't helped. What else I must do?

Answer (score 10):

It needs to be executable and installed.

Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/YOUR_SCRIPT
```

Install it to all runlevels:

```
sudo update-rc.d YOUR_SCRIPT defaults
```

Now restart and see your script gets run at startup.

Have Fun!

[edit]

Btw. Your script is a service now. You could always stop/start/restart it with

```
sudo service YOUR_SCRIPT stop/start/restart
```

[/edit]

Comment: not work in 18.04

Comment: correct, update-rc.d is outdated. refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197727/how-to-start-svnserve-with-systemctl-systemd/40584047#40584047 for an up-to-date example on how to install something as a service.